# Searching string for double quotes

Tags: vba

When searching for a double quote using Instr, I know that you need to use 4 double quotes for the search string `Instr(String,"""")`, or alternatively, `Instr(String, Chr(34))`.
What I don't quite understand is why 3 double quotes don't work `Instr(String,""")`

I have Googled for this, but haven't come across the answer I'm looking for. I realize this is a very basic question, but I can't seem to get my head around it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `""` is just quoting a `"` - therefore, `"""` means `"_here comes a double quote` - and VBA lacks the closing `"`!

In other words:

- `x = ""` -> Content of is blank
- `x = """"` -> Content of x is `"`
- `x = """` -> VBA cannot compile, as it reads here comes a string (the first `"`) that contains a double quote (`""`) - but then does not find the closing `"`...

Comment: Thanks for your answer Peter.  I need to ponder this for a while, will get back to you asap, possibly with a followup question(s).

Comment: I guess this is what's puzzling me - why not - VBA cannot compile, as it reads here comes a string (the first ") that contains one double quote ("), followed by a closing "...?

Comment: don't ask me, why the error message is not the way you imagine it! I guess the compiler simple doesn't find the end of the line/string and complains... ;-)

Comment: Sorry, typo at my end.  Should have read "read it as here comes a string (the first ") that contains 1 double quote ("), followed by a closing "...?, and no error.  I'm thinking that "xxx" is ok, then with """, the middle " is taking the place of xxx.

Comment: Found out it also depends on whether imbedding strings or concatenating strings.  Not completely intuitive (yet)!  Thanks for your help.